# Batch output redirection when using start command for GUI app

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, output-redirect

This is the scenario:

We have a Python script that starts a Windows batch file and redirects its output to a file. Afterwards it reads the file and then tries to delete it:

```
os.system(C:\batch.bat >C:\temp.txt 2>&1)
os.remove(C:\temp.txt)
```

In the batch.bat we start a Windows GUI programm like this:

```
start c:\the_programm.exe
```

Thats all in the batch fíle.

Now the os.remove() fails with "Permission denied" because the temp.txt is still locked by the system. It seems this is caused by the still runing the_programm.exe (whos output also seems to be redirected to the temp.txt).

Any idea how to start the_programm.exe without having the temp.txt locked while it is still running? The Python part is hardly changeable as this is a tool ([BusyB](http://busyb.sourceforge.net/)).

In fact I do not need the output of the_programm.exe, so the essence of the question is: **How do I decouple the_programm.exe from locking temp.txt for its output?**
Or: **How do I use START or another Windows command to start a program without inheriting the batch output redirection?**

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you started the program and read directly from its output stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could find a proper solution:

I am not using a batch file anymore for starting the_programm.exe, but a Python script:

```
from subprocess import Popen

     if __name__ == '__main__':
          Popen('C:/the_programm.exe', close_fds=True)
```

The close_fds parameter decouples the file handles from the .exe process! That's it!

Comment: Nice! I was going to suggest a C program that used fclose(stdin); fclose(stdout); which is basically the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit hacky, but you could try it. It uses the `AT` command to run `the_programm.exe` up to a minute in the future (which it computes using the `%TIME%` environment variable and `SET` arithmetic).

batch.bat:

```
@echo off
setlocal
:: store the current time so it does not change while parsing
set t=%time%
:: parse hour, minute, second
set h=%t:~0,2%
set m=%t:~3,2%
set s=%t:~6,2%
:: reduce strings to simple integers
if "%h:~0,1%"==" " set h=%h:~1%
if "%m:~0,1%"=="0" set m=%m:~1%
if "%s:~0,1%"=="0" set s=%s:~1%
:: choose number of seconds in the future; granularity for AT is one
:: minute, plus we need a few extra seconds for this script to run
set x=70
:: calculate hour and minute to run the program
set /a x=s + x
set /a s="x %% 60"
set /a x=m + x / 60
set /a m="x %% 60"
set /a h=h + x / 60
set /a h="h %% 24"
:: schedule the program to run
at %h%:%m% c:\the_programm.exe
```

You can look at the `AT /?` and `SET /?` to see what each of these is doing. I left off the `/interactive` parameter of `AT` since you commented that "no user interaction is allowed".

Caveats:

- It appears that `%TIME%` is always 24-hour time, regardless of locale settings in the control panel, but I don't have any proof of this.
- If your system is loaded down and batch.bat takes more than 10 seconds to run, the `AT` command will be scheduled to run 1 day later. You can recover this manually, using `AT {job} /delete`, and increase the `x=70` to something more acceptable.

The `START` command, unfortunately, even when given `/i` to ignore the current environment, seems to pass along the open file descriptors of the parent `cmd.exe` process. These file descriptors appear to be handed off to subprocesses, even if the subprocesses are redirected to NUL, and are kept open even if intermediate shell processes terminate. You can see this in [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) if you have a batch file which `START`s another batch file which `START`s another batch file (etc.) which `START`s a GUI Windows app. Once the intermediate batch files have terminated, the GUI app will own the file handles, even if it (and the intermediate batch files) were all redirected to `NUL`.

Comment: Great answer! Any idea if it would help if I used some WSH script instead of a batch file to start the .exe?

Comment: I would bet that WSH/PowerShell/etc. have a better way to do this (perhaps even a real 'fork'), but I'm not familiar with those. I keep up with CMD only because I have been using batch files for decades.

Comment: I tried your script but could not get it working. As the Taskplaner service runs under a System account I do not get the program window somehow. Changing the service to my account did not work. But see my answer for the solution I could find.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Windows will let you delete an open file.  Sounds like you're wanting to throw away the program's output; would redirecting to 'nul' instead do what you need?

Comment: Sure you can delete open files. It just depends on how you open that file (cf. CreateFile documentation).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, this is the issue, and what he wants to do:

1. Make *no* changes to the python code.
2. The Python code is written assuming that "temp.txt" is no longer being used when this function returns:

   os.system(C:\batch.bat >C:\temp.txt 2>&1)
3. This is in fact not the case because "batch.bat" spawns an interactive GUI program using the "start" command.

How about changing your "batch.bat" file to contain:

```
start c:\the_programm.exe
pause
```

This will keep the "batch.bat" file running until you hit a key on that window.  Once you hit a key, the "os.system" python command will return, and then python will call "os.remove".

Comment: You understood the problem correctly, but the pause is excactly what I do not want to do: The Python script has to continue with the_program.exe still runing.

Comment: As this is used for automation, no user interaction is allowed.

Comment: @desolat: Sorry, I know what I would do in Linux (fork a new process and cut the parent-child relationship) but I don't know how to do that on Windows.  Hopefully somebody else does.

Comment: @Greg: true, true, that's the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Are you closing the file after you're done reading it?  The following works at my end:

```
import os

os.system('runbat.bat > runbat.log 2>&1')
f = open('runbat.log')
print f.read()
f.close()
os.remove('runbat.log')
```

but fails if I remove the `f.close()` line.

Comment: You missed the thing with the started and still running .exe in the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Why capture to a file if you're just deleting it immediately?

How about this:

```
os.system(C:\batch.bat >nul 2>&1)
```

EDIT: Oops, I missed your comment about reading the file, I only noticed the code.